# Is there any ways to extract the number of views a webpage recieved?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Looking for any tools (preferably in python) to extract the number of views a particular webpage received. If not, it would be also handy to know if there is any other webpage specific analytics that I can obtain (such as the one listed)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you own this particular webpage there is no way to see how much visitors/views/traffic it gets. Visits are measured with Analytics injected into the site (e.g. Google Analytics) or by reading the server logs. Both of which you cannot access unless you own the site.

There are some sites that make estimates available in an API. For example:

- https://www.sitetrafficapi.com/
- https://www.alexa.com/